# Map entry appears in HashMap.entrySet() but not internal HashMap.table

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, hashmap

I have a Java HashHap that is getting populated within the program. For some reason the entrySet within the map contains what I am expecting, but when I look at the internal Entry table it is missing a value. Since that value is missing I'm getting a null and it breaks everything. Maybe I don't understand HashMaps as well as I thought but should the table contain all the entries in the entrySet? Thanks.

When talking about entrySet and the table I am indeed talking about the internals of the HashMap when debugging. Here is what my "entrySet" looks like:

```
[IS_DELETED=0, COLLECTION_SET_NAME=D-EIUCFOE-SET, MAP_ID=Ic65fd5ffb7c311e09fc6842b2ba7e81a, PRODUCT_ID=1, USER_ID=U0158703, WM_DIFFVER=DiffBase, DISTRICT_CODE=TX_N_DIS, WM_CODE=NC, MODIFIED_DATE=2012-09-04 10:13:08.973]
```

And here is what my table looks like:

```
[IS_DELETED=0, COLLECTION_SET_NAME=D-EIUCFOE-SET, null, null, PRODUCT_ID=1, null, null, null, WM_DIFFVER=DiffBase, null, DISTRICT_CODE=TX_N_DIS, WM_CODE=NC, MODIFIED_DATE=2012-09-04 10:13:08.973, null, null, null]
```

So when my code looks for the MAP_ID once this HashMap is created, it comes up with a null and it blows up.

```
table   HashMap$Entry<K,V>[16]  (id=248)    
    [0] HashMap$Entry<K,V>  (id=270)    
        hash    -1013369904 
        key "IS_DELETED" (id=883)   
        next    null    
        value   BigDecimal  (id=884)    
    [1] HashMap$Entry<K,V>  (id=271)    
        hash    449814449   
        key "COLLECTION_SET_NAME" (id=896)  
        next    HashMap$Entry<K,V>  (id=898)    
        value   "D-EIUCFOE-SET" (id=899)    
    [2] null    
    [3] null    
    [4] HashMap$Entry<K,V>  (id=275)    
        hash    -1942791868 
        key "PRODUCT_ID" (id=900)   
        next    HashMap$Entry<K,V>  (id=901)    
        value   BigDecimal  (id=902)    
    [5] null    
    [6] null    
    [7] null    
    [8] HashMap$Entry<K,V>  (id=276)    
        hash    -1109968520 
        key "WM_DIFFVER" (id=904)   
        next    null    
        value   "DiffBase" (id=905) 
    [9] null    
    [10]    HashMap$Entry<K,V>  (id=278)    
        hash    -1920690854 
        key "DISTRICT_CODE" (id=906)    
        next    null    
        value   "TX_N_DIS" (id=907) 
    [11]    HashMap$Entry<K,V>  (id=279)    
        hash    -1948303941 
        key "WM_CODE" (id=909)  
        next    null    
        value   "NC" (id=910)   
    [12]    HashMap$Entry<K,V>  (id=280)    
        hash    1002278668  
        key "MODIFIED_DATE" (id=912)    
        next    null    
        value   TIMESTAMP  (id=913) 
    [13]    null    
    [14]    null    
    [15]    null
```

I can't get a hold of the MAP_ID Entry but that is coming back from the database as a String.

Comment: Which table? can you show us some code?

Comment: By "entry table", do you mean the `HashMap`'s internals when looking at it in the debugger?

Comment: what are you using for keys?  my guess is that your keys have broken hashcode/equals implementations, and therefore your lookups are failing.  (note that the internal hash table is a bucket where each bucket is a _linked list_ of entries)

Comment: More information has been added.

Comment: A List of Hashmaps is filled by a jdbc query to a database. The code isn't going give much more insight. And in this case it only returns one hashmap.

Comment: i already explained why the table looks the way it does.  you haven't answered what your keys are.  you want help, but don't provide info...

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding what you mean by keys if the examples above aren't what you are looking for?

Comment: The example is a print out.  it doesn't tell me anything about what class types you are using.

Comment: The .toString() for the hashmaps internal (private) table is misleading. It does not print out all map entries, only the first entry in each bucket is printed.

Comment: @ColinD - yes, i already mentioned that in my first comment.

Comment: @jtahlborn just making what you said more explicit, to avoid further confusion.

Comment: @ColinD - good point, thanks.

Comment: Pretty much all bets are off if you're going to mess around with the private internals of someone else's class. There's no guarantee `HashMap.table` will continue behaving the way it does currently, or even that it will continue to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's clarify a few things.

1. `Map.Entry` is a logical "entry" in your map. Let's refer to it as a "map entry"
2. `HashMap.table` is an internal array of the `HashMap` `Map` implementation, storing lists of "map entries" with colliding `hashCode` modulo values. Note that several "map entries" are contained in such a "hashmap table entry" (also referred to as "bucket")

Look at this "hashmap table entry" for instance:

```
[4] HashMap$Entry<K,V>  (id=275)    
    hash    -1942791868 
    key "PRODUCT_ID" (id=900)   
    next    HashMap$Entry<K,V>  (id=901)    
    value   BigDecimal  (id=902)
```

Observe, that it links to `id=901`, which is the "next" "map entry" for the same hash value (or more precisely, `hash % 16 == 4`). The basic idea is this:

```
// "HashMap table" has 16 "hashmap table entries" (at first, before growing)
[0] with   1 "hashmap entry"
[1] with > 1 "hashmap entry"
[2] empty
[3] empty
...
```

While a `HashMap` grows, it may choose to enlarge its internal "hashmap table", in order to optimise the distribution of "map entries" across its "hashmap table". E.g. if the "hashmap table" has a size of 256, the modulo applied to `hashCode()` values will be 256 as well, reducing the `hashCode()` collision risk

Comment: Overlooked that, not thinking today. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may come from the fact that Java is storing stuff in buckets which itself are an implementation of the list. This is an interesting article:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html

Can you provide us with some code so we can offer some real help?

Comment: And as Lukas commented- not to get objects in the same bucket you need to make unique hashCode implementation.